# eclipse rcp 4 export

Tags: eclipse, export, rcp

I'm trying to export my eclipse rcp 4 application so I can start it from other devices without installing eclipse. The application rusn fine in eclipse but is giving me following errorlog when I try to start the exported product version.

```
!SESSION 2016-02-22 09:40:38.024 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_66
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -clearPersistedState
!ENTRY RCPCAN 4 0 2016-02-22 09:40:38.418
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: RCPCAN [2]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.ui
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2016-02-22 09:40:38.617
!MESSAGE Product RCPCAN.product could not be found.

!ENTRY RCPCAN 2 0 2016-02-22 09:40:38.816
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: RCPCAN [2]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.ui
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-02-22 09:40:38.817
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI$URIPool$PlatformAccessUnit.setValue(URI.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI$URIPool.intern(URI.java:1949)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI.createPlatformPluginURI(URI.java:2718)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.determineApplicationModelURI(E4Application.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

[image]

Here's my build.properties file. What can I do to solves this problem?

Comment: How are you building the RCP? Are you using a .product file?

Comment: yes, I use the eclipse product export wizard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing plugins from your RCP build (org.eclipse.ui in particular).

Your .product file must list all the plugins that are needed by your RCP (or features if you are using a feature based build).

Open the .product file editor and switch to the Contents tab. Make sure your own plugins are all listed there and then press 'Add Required' to add all the core Eclipse plugins that are needed.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to help. I don't get any error messages anymore, but the window that is opening is completly empty. Can I see the error messages of the application somehow?

Comment: Start from the command line and specify the -consoleLog and -debug options

Comment: Okay the exported application seems to have some sort of problem with my jface PreferenceStore and I can't seem to solve it. I specified an absolute path though it keeps telling me that it can't find it. does that have some kind of connection to the eclipse.properties not beeing found?

Comment: That has nothing to do with your original question. Accept this question and ask a new question.